# How can I consume IIS7's FREB programatically

Tags: iis-7, trace, freb

IIS 7 has a very useful feature called [Failed Request Tracing](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/dunnry/Failed-Request-Tracing-on-IIS7/#356252) (FREB for short). It has a very nice visualization feature, involving an extremely complex XSL stylsheet that parses the results into a useful treeview.

I, however, want to consume FREB programatically, and be able to present the results on my smart client (without waiting for the XML to be written server-side).

The only possible solution I found so far, involves compiling an IIS7 C++ plugin that converts FREB into OutputDebugStrings, an approach even the writer suggets should not be used on a production server ([here's the article](http://blogs.iis.net/rickjames/archive/2007/10/10/iis-7-c-module-api-sample-consuming-trace-events.aspx))

My question is: is there another approach?

As always, my thanks for reading, and even more for replying.
Guy

Comment: interesting.  I didn't know about FREB. I'm interested in the answer, too.